# Return a Map from a hibernate query

Tags: java, hashmap

In the below query on passing a list of office codes, I get a list of countryID's. Now instead of that, I need a Map In which the key will be countryID and its value as the list of office codes. Can you please help me.

Example: If we have offices as **abc, def** belong to country **123** and **xyz** belongs to **789**, I need a Map like
**(123, List(abc,def).... (789,List(xyz)))**

```
public List getData(List officeCode) {

    try {
        StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer("select distinct 
        (abc.countryID)  from com.#####.TABLE table");
        queryString.append(" where table.officeCode in (:oCode)");
        return SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery(queryString.toString())
        .setParameterList("oCode",officeCode )
        .list();
    }
    catch (Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following query:

```
select distinct abc.countryID, abc.officeCode from SomeEntity abc where abc.officeCode in (:codes)
```

This query will return a `List<Object[]>`, each object array containing a countryID as first element and an office code as second element.

Then iterate through the list, and populate your map.

Note: using a StringBuffer to concatenate String literals is counter-productive, and less readable. You'd better simply do:

```
String queryString = "select distinct (abc.countryID)  from com.#####.TABLE table"
                     + " where table.officeCode in (:oCode)";
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending not to use StringBuffer. I have a .list(); at the end of the code. Will that remain as it is? What is the use of having it?

Comment: `.list()` executes the query and returns the list of its results. Once you have this list, you convert it to a map.